# Android Studio loop ImageView Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, assets

I'm working on a little project and have run into some trouble.

I made an asset that I want to use in my fragment over the navbar of my app:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0.00 0.00 1007.00 135.00">
<path fill="#a27630" d="
  M 1007.00 51.81
  L 1007.00 135.00
  L 0.00 135.00
  L 0.00 53.02
  L 42.58 0.54
  Q 43.00 0.03 43.41 0.54
  L 84.87 51.64
  A 0.18 0.17 -44.1 0 0 85.14 51.64
  L 126.78 0.28
  A 0.29 0.29 0.0 0 1 127.22 0.28
  L 168.86 51.64
  A 0.18 0.18 0.0 0 0 169.14 51.64
  L 210.67 0.43
  A 0.42 0.42 0.0 0 1 211.33 0.42
  L 252.86 51.64
  A 0.18 0.18 0.0 0 0 253.14 51.64
  L 294.56 0.55
  Q 295.00 0.01 295.44 0.55
  L 336.64 51.36
  Q 337.00 51.81 337.36 51.36
  L 378.56 0.55
  Q 379.00 0.01 379.44 0.55
  L 420.86 51.64
  A 0.18 0.18 0.0 0 0 421.14 51.64
  L 462.56 0.55
  Q 463.00 0.01 463.44 0.55
  L 504.64 51.36
  Q 505.00 51.81 505.36 51.36
  L 546.56 0.55
  Q 547.00 0.01 547.44 0.55
  L 588.86 51.64
  A 0.18 0.18 0.0 0 0 589.14 51.64
  L 630.56 0.55
  Q 631.00 0.01 631.44 0.55
  L 672.64 51.36
  Q 673.00 51.81 673.36 51.36
  L 714.56 0.55
  Q 715.00 0.01 715.44 0.55
  L 756.86 51.64
  A 0.18 0.18 0.0 0 0 757.14 51.64
  L 798.72 0.36
  A 0.36 0.36 0.0 0 1 799.28 0.36
  L 840.30 50.95
  Q 840.50 51.19 840.70 50.95
  L 881.72 0.36
  A 0.36 0.36 0.0 0 1 882.28 0.36
  L 923.30 50.95
  Q 923.50 51.19 923.70 50.95
  L 964.76 0.32
  A 0.32 0.31 44.5 0 1 965.25 0.32
  L 1007.00 51.81
  Z"
/>
</svg>
```

In order to make it look consistent with my in-app design, I rotated the asset inside my `ConstraintLayout` by setting the `rotation` attribute. Like this:

[image: Rotated Spikes]

As I want to give the illusion of the spikes to continuously scroll to the left, I added the `imageView` a second time, with the goal of making the second imageView appear when the first one is out of the screen, and the first one reappear when the second one is out of the screen.

This code desribes what I did so far:

```html
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView bottomSpikes1;
private ImageView bottomSpikes2;

public AccountFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static AccountFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    bottomSpikes1 = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_spikes_1);
    bottomSpikes2 = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_spikes_2);

    startContinuousScrolling();

    return view;
}

private void startContinuousScrolling() {
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    int animationSpeed = 8000;

    // Animate the first ImageView to move from right to left
    PropertyValuesHolder spikes1_pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", 0f, -screenWidth);
    /*PropertyValuesHolder spikes_pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationY", 0, 50);*/
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(bottomSpikes1, spikes1_pvhX);
    animator.setDuration(animationSpeed);
    animator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

    // Animate the second ImageView to follow the first one seamlessly
    PropertyValuesHolder spikes2_pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", screenWidth, 0f);
    ObjectAnimator followAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(bottomSpikes2, spikes2_pvhX);
    followAnimator.setDuration(animationSpeed);
    followAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

    // Create a set of animators to run in parallel
    AnimatorSet loadingAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
    loadingAnimation.playTogether(animator, followAnimator);
    loadingAnimation.setInterpolator(new android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator());

    loadingAnimation.start();
}

}
```

This makes the imageviews appear one after another, and creates a continuous scrolling effect, but there's one problem: When the imageViews go into each other,their y-coordinates aren't aligned correctly, so the transition from one imageView to the other looks bad.

[image: Jarring transition]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve the proper behavior with the imageViews? I tried setting the `transitionY` value after each image reappeared, but it didn't work, and I feel like the method is blocked by my infinitely occuring animation.